# Xml serialization remove inner tags

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the desired xml serialization that I want. Thanks beforehand for your help.

So, the xml that I am aiming for looks something like this:

```
<ChangeSet>
    <Change class="object" key="foo">
        bar
    </Change>
    <Change class="testing" key="temp">
        temp
    </Change>
</ChangeSet>
```

What I'm actually getting is:

```
<ChangeSet>
    <Change class="object" key="foo">
        <Value> bar </Value>
    </Change>
    <Change class="testing" key="temp">
        <Value> temp </Value>
    </Change>
</ChangeSet>
```

Note that the value inside of the Value tags need to be able to be any object. (Collection, object, generic type... etc)
How can I get rid of the Value tags?

C# code:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("ChangeSet")]
public class ChangeSet
{
    [XmlElement("Change", typeof(Change))]
    public List<Change> Changes;
}
public class Change
{
    [XmlAttribute("Class")]
    public string Class;

    [XmlAttribute("Description")]
    public string Key;

    public object Value;
}


StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType());
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true
};

using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(xml))
{
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Removes the xsd & xsi namespace declarations from the xml
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, objToSerialize, ns);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [XmlText] attribute over Value of type string

```
[XMLText]
public string Value;
```

or use another string property and ignore the Value property

```
[XMLIgnore]
public object Value;

[XMLText]
public string ValueString
{
  get{ return this.Value.ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, it says that XmlText can not be used on complex values

Comment: then you have to change Value type to String (public string Value;) else it will be considered complex type

Comment: if this is not possible another alternative is to 1. mark Value as XMLIgnore 2. Create another property (ValueString of type string ) and  in its getter return Value.ToString();

Comment: but it won't be just a string. It could be an object, collection or generic type

Comment: If it is a Collection or Generic type it would mean that you would need the additional tags(for collection items or Type information) also so that the object can then be de-serialised again.